# NUget: Unable to extract metadata from obj

Tags: visual-studio-2013, msbuild, nuget

When building a nuget package from Visual Studio 2013 Update 4 with NuGet 2.8.3 I get the following warnings:

```
EXEC : warning : Unable to extract metadata from 'MyAssembly.dll'. [D:\Development\MyAssembly\MyAssembly.csproj]
EXEC : warning : Description was not specified. Using 'Description'. [D:\Development\MyAssembly\MyAssembly.csproj]
EXEC : warning : Author was not specified. Using 'GDo'. [D:\Development\MyAssembly\MyAssembly.csproj]
EXEC : warning : Unable to extract metadata from 'MyAssembly.dll'. [D:\Development\MyAssembly\MyAssembly.csproj]
EXEC : warning : Description was not specified. Using 'Description'. [D:\Development\MyAssembly\MyAssembly.csproj]
EXEC : warning : Author was not specified. Using 'GDo'. [D:\Development\MyAssembly\MyAssembly.csproj]
```

The generated nuget package is then named MyAssembly.**1.0.0.0**.nupkg while I was expecting 1.4.4

Despite having the following AssemblyInfo.cs

```
using System.Reflection;

// General Information about an assembly is controlled through the following 
// set of attributes. Change these attribute values to modify the information
// associated with an assembly.
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("MyAssembly")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("components and factory")]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")] // change this when the interface changes
[assembly: AssemblyInformationalVersion("1.4.4")] // used by the NuGet pack implementation
```

I am using the following post-build event:

```
"$(DEVTOOLS)\NuGet\NuGet.exe" pack "$(ProjectPath)" -symbols -IncludeReferencedProjects -Properties "Configuration=$(Configuration);Platform=$(Platform);OutputPath=Obj\$(Configuration)" -NonInteractive -MinClientVersion 2.5
```

We use this post-build event on all projects and they all produce the correct packages, both in Visual Studio and on the TFS CI build server.

When I run msbuild from the command line for this particular project I can see the nuget command is invoked as:

```
"D:\DevTools\NuGet\NuGet.exe" pack "D:\Development\MyAssembly\MyAssembly.csproj" -symbols -IncludeReferencedProjects -Properties "Configuration=Debug;Platform=AnyCPU;OutputPath=Obj\Debug" -NonInteractive -MinClientVersion 2.5
Attempting to build package from 'MyAssembly\MyAssembly.csproj'.
Packing files from 'D:\Development\MyAssembly\Obj\Debug'.
EXEC : warning : Unable to extract metadata from 'MyAssembly.dll' [D:\Development\MyAssembly\MyAssembly.csproj]
File from dependency is not changed. File 'native.dll' is not added.
Found packages.config. Using packages listed as dependencies
EXEC : warning : Description was not specified. Using 'Description'. [D:\Development\MyAssembly\MyAssembly.csproj]
EXEC : warning : Author was not specified. Using 'GDo'. [D:\Development\MyAssembly\MyAssembly.csproj]
Successfully created package 'D:\Development\MyAssembly\bin\Debug\MyAssembly.1.0.0.0.nupkg'.
```

When I change this command to reference the bin folder instead of the obj folder:

```
"D:\DevTools\NuGet\NuGet.exe" pack "D:\Development\MyAssembly\MyAssembly.csproj" -symbols -IncludeReferencedProjects -Properties "Configuration=Debug;Platform=AnyCPU;OutputPath=**bin**\Debug" -NonInteractive -MinClientVersion 2.5
```

I get the expected behaviour, the package builds as expected with the correct version etc:

```
Attempting to build package from 'MyAssembly.csproj'.
Packing files from 'D:\Development\MyAssembly\bin\Debug'.
File from dependency is not changed. File 'native.dll' is not added.
Found packages.config. Using packages listed as dependencies
Successfully created package 'D:\Development\MyAssembly\MyAssembly.1.4.4.nupkg'.
```

But this is just weird. The post build event works with all other projects, for example

```
  "D:\DevTools\NuGet\NuGet.exe" pack "D:\Development\MyOtherAssembly\MyOtherAssembly.csproj" -symbols -IncludeReferencedP
  rojects -Properties "Configuration=Debug;Platform=AnyCPU;OutputPath=Obj\Debug" -NonInteractive -MinClientVersion 2.5
  Attempting to build package from 'MyOtherAssembly.csproj'.
  Packing files from 'D:\Development\MyOtherAssembly\Obj\Debug'.
  Found packages.config. Using packages listed as dependencies
  Successfully created package 'D:\Development\MyOtherAssembly\bin\Debug\MyOtherAssembly.1.4.1.nupkg'.
```

Even weirder is that the build of the broken project works just fine on another developer's machine with the same sourcecode. Manally runnig msbuild does yield the same errors but the generated package has the correct version. (yes, I tried getting a new source tree from TFS, to no avail)
Can someone explain what could be the cause?

Update: After checking in, our TFS server now has the same build issue and generates nuget package version 1.0.0.0 only.

Comment: Have you tried doing a Clean Build? It's possible you have some cruft from a previous build that is causing issues.

Comment: Yes, I did, tried clean, build, rebuild, release, debug, all kinds of configuration, to no avail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cause of the packaging failure was hidden by nuget. When we manually built a package with the switch  **-Verbosity detailed** 
we received a complete stacktrace from nuget, with a FileNotFoundException on a dependent dll, in our case log4net. And indeed, this dll is not copied to the obj folder.

We narrowed it down to the following attribute in one of our classes:

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]
```

This caused nuget to look for log4net.dll the moment it started reading assembly metadata. We verified this by copying the log4net dll to the obj folder. (build succeeded) We then removed this attribute and this solved the issue completely.

Comment: I have just had the same issue but when creating a Xamarin.iOS NuGet package, I tried the test above by copying the Xamarin.iOS DLL manually, whcih worked however the solution for me was to mark the particular assembly as Copy Local = True

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the behaviour because nuget wasn't picking up the version number from my assemblies. The message above was only shown by nuget 2.8.6 but I was using 3.5 and/or 4.0 which doesn't report the warning but also fails to extract the metadata.

The problem for me was caused by me having several version of nuget and renaming the executable to match the version. I'd renamed the 2.8.6 version to `nuget.2.8.6.exe`, the 3.5 version to `nuget.3.5.0.exe` and the 4.0 version to `nuget.4.0.0.exe`. The `fuslogvw` output for 3.5 showed that it couldn't find the file `nuget3.5.0.exe.config` and this seemed to cause the problem.

As soon as I renamed the executable back to `nuget.exe` everything started working again.